# Can't add to JSON object for data storage

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to write data to a JSON object that I read from a file and save to a file, but when I try to add data to it nothing happens.

Here is the code where I try to write to the object:
(Note: saveData() is a function i created to save to a file using node.js)

```
let id = message.member.user.id;
if(coins.hasOwnProperty(id)){
    message.reply("you have " + coins[id] + " coins.");
} else {
    coins[id] = 0;
    message.reply("you have " + coins[id] + " coins.");
}
saveData(coins,"coinData.dat");
```

What gets printed is that "you have undefined coins."

This is for a discord bot and I need to get it working, but I don't know what the problem is.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The coins doesn't contain the id key. Is the `coins` an array maybe?

Comment: no it's not, it's a json object

Comment: So you have a falsy value: `{ foo: undefined }`. In this case `hasOwnProperty` returns true, but the value is undefined

Comment: no, it doesnt return true.

Comment: could you add the console log for `coins` and `id`? It will be simple to check then

Comment: i did, it returns a regular discord user id.
example id: 358736445361487872

Comment: this works..
```
const aNumber = 358736445361487872
const coins = { [aNumber]: 'hello' }
console.log(coins.hasOwnProperty(aNumber))
console.log(coins[aNumber])
```

Comment: i assume the problem is that it's being loaded from a file, i just dont know why that problem would occur.